# Программа игнорирует getline если есть if

Tags: c++

Если код такой:

```
void rewrite(string *b) {
        string c;
        getline(cin, c);
        *b = c;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        string b;
        
        cout << "Please enter a string" << endl;
        getline(cin, b);
        rewrite(&b);
        cout << b;
```

То программа работает отлично. А если такой:

```
    void rewrite(string *b) {
                string c;
                getline(cin, c);
                *b = c;
            }
            
            int main()
            {
                string b;
                
                cout << "Please enter a string" << endl;
                getline(cin, b);
char userinput;
    cin >> userinput;
                if (userinput == 'f') {
            rewrite(&b);
            cout << b;
        }
```

то программа игнорирует getline из функции rewrite.
Сама программа должна перезаписывать строку на новую, которую введет пользователь. Переменная userinput нужна для создания консольного меню. Например, при вводе f в консоль запускалась данная функция ввода новой строки, при вводе другого char другая функция и тд.

Comment: Что такое `userinput`?

Comment: Вводите Вы в строку `b`, сравниваете какой-то `userinput`, причем сравниваете с символом...

Comment: char userinput;
cin >> userinput;

Comment: где это должно быть?  Исправьте код в вопросе.

Comment: Исправил, пожалуйста посмотрите.

Comment: После ввода символа в буфере остается символ новой строки, который потом читает `getline` и думает, что это пустая строка

Comment: Кроме того, у Вас в приведенном коде какие-то сложности с фигурными скобками. проверьте, это ошибка в коде, или просто сюда не все скопировалось?

Comment: вашу ошибку получить не получается. Укажите операционку и компилятор.

Comment: За что ж Вы нас так не любите?.. Поправьте отступы в коде, будьте человечны.

Comment: в инструкции http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/ говориться, что символ новой строки удаляется. `If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded (i.e. it is not stored and the next input operation will begin after it).` Вы что-то умалчиваете.

Answer (score -1):

```
char userinput;
    cin >> userinput;
    cin.ignore();
```

Помогло добавление cin.ignore(); после cin >> как сказал пользователь EOF